# Is there something wrong when I call the WMS GetCapabilities Request in QGIS with basic authentication?

Tags: python, qgis

Here is the code. That I'm trying to do, but this is not working like GetCapabilities URL.

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setParam('url' , 'http://localhost:8443/geoserver/test/ows?service=WMS&layers=test:2-0&crs=EPSG:3857&styles=')
uri.setUsername('testing')
uri.setPassword('sd6idfs')
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(uri.uri(False), '2-0', 'WMS')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

WARNING  :  Download of capabilities failed: Protocol "" is unknown

Please tell me where I'm wrong. Or how to pass getcapabilities url in qgis with username or password.
Not like this form

```
http://username:password@localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms?
```

Because when I'm trying to like this it's working for me but only with single request like GetMap request not the list. And also username and password not hiding on layer tooltip.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, there is also https://gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: try `http://localhost:8443/geoserver/test/ows?service=WMS&request=getCapabilities`